# Can I move on to React without knowing JS inside out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

If I have had experience with JS, yet still need to learn a lot more, es6 and up, would it be ok to start on React or Vue? I recently graduated and it seems like a lot of companies like the sound of you knowing react, Angular or Vue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first learn the basics of vanilla JavaScript and modern syntax  and features found in ES6. Like Jared said above, frameworks come and go. If your fundamentals in JavaScript are strong, you would easily be able to pick up on any framework/library. Also, as you learn/work on a framework, keep practicing coding in vanilla JS side by side. That will strengthen your JS skills.

Some of the things you should know before you start with a framework are:

1. Object-oriented JavaScript - classes, constructors, methods, inheritance.
2. ES6 syntax/features - arrow functions, let/const, importing/exporting modules
3. higher-order array methods

Also, you should think of where you want to work - at a large MNC or a startup or if you want to freelance.

Most large companies, that make enterprise level apps, use Angular because it provides a strict framework to follow. React and Vue are much more relaxed in terms of how you implement things.

For Angular, you might need to have some knowledge of TypeScript, which, again, won't be difficult to learn if your JS basics are clear.

I would suggest you go through the basics of JS and then pick one of Angular, React or Vue and then give some time regularly to vanilla JS.

Word of caution: Do not get into the argument of which framework is better than the others. You will find many such videos/articles that try to prove one is better or worse than the rest, but, trust me, all that matters is your skills in vanilla JS.

Best of luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

React is javascript so learning React means learning javascript, But You cannot learn React without JavaScript or without knowing JavaScript in the first place. In comparison to other frontend solutions, React makes heavily use of JavaScript, So get some basic and advance javascript experience.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer will be yes you can. I did the same. I had very little knowledge of javascript before I started with React. You will learn javascript while you learn to React because React is essentially just javascript.

You will be using all the things while you will be learning to React like class, let, spread operator and lot more. I will suggest to watch a few small tutorials and can jump right into developing something ad you will learn along the way.

That being said I will suggest you build on your javascript basics while you learn React because there is a new framework every few months. So in summary just start learning without thinking.

Comment: Dig it. Thanks for the quick response. I have a whole Udemy course on React that I put on hold until I was better at JS, can't wait to dive in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be an expert in JS to start with React, for example, but you need to know at least the basics of this language, and other things like algorithms and data structures. I recommend also to study how React or other JS library works, in order to don't be stuck with the basics of this libraries.